# View JasperReport inside Swing JFrame

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jasper-plugin

I have created jasperReport(v6.0) with Eclipse-Luna plugin. When I view the report, it will open new window with report.  I want to display this report inside the *same Java Swing window* (JDK 1.8).

Below code will open JasperViewer in new window

```
String reportPath = "reports/report.jrxml";
try {
    JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportPath);
    JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, null, conn);
    JasperViewer.viewReport(jp);
    conn.close();
} catch (Exception e1) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: But I want to display report inside the same window

Comment: Which window?! Post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help.

Comment: *"..inside the same window"*  `CardLayout`...

Comment: I am using swing JFrame form with button. When I press the button, the report should display below the button (inside a JPanel object or similar) and report should not open a new window.